# How To Call Different Function on React Nested Div onClick Event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, web-deployment, react-functional-component

I have a nested div in react like this:

```
<div onClick={() => fn_01()}>
   <div onClick={() => fn_02()}>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to call different function when user click those div. But when I click the 1st div it called `fn_01()` and when I click the 2nd div it also call `fn_01()`. How can I solve this issue.

I am using functional component in my react project. I also implement Class component and call those method using `this.`, which doesn't work also. I need this work in Functional Component

Comment: In a comment on an answer, you said you'd tried `stopPropagtion` but it didn't work. ItIt does work, if you do it properly. Part of the problem with your code is that you're creating a wrapper function: `onClick={() => fn_02()}`. Instead, just pass `fn_02` directly as the click handler: `onClick={fn_02}`. Then, declare the `event` parameter in `fn_02`: `function fn_02(event)` and in the body of the function call `event.stopPropagation()`. (If you wanted to keep the wrapper, you'd need to pass the `event`: `onClick={(event) => fn_02(event)}`.)

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to place a call to `event.stopPropagation()` in your child `onClick` method. This will prevent the parent from being called.

Comment: I try  this one also but doesn't work for me

Comment: It does work if you do it properly.